# Put data to array from JSON array in android

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-asynctask

EDIT after proper initialisation but everything works but I still get only the first object in "events" array. Why ?

I've an AsyncTask which connects to server to download JSON file and to get JSON array from there. The problem is that when I want to extract another data from the same array using for loop I got a null pointer exception. Why ? I am extracting the values "lat","lon","text" from array "events". 
Here is how my JSON looks :

```
{
"current_ts": 1425907330,
"username": "guri",
"events": [
    {
        "id": 16591481,
        "ts": 1425907325,
        "lat": 48.17,
        "lon": 17.13,
        "likes": 5,
        "text": "Poziar na hlavnej stanici",
        "tags": "#poziar #stanica #hori",
        "img": "2002-06-19.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 47067411,
        "ts": 1425907100,
        "lat": 48.81,
        "lon": 17.22,
        "likes": 0,
        "text": "V Bille je velky vypredaj",
        "tags": [
            {
                "tag1": "#akcia",
                "tag2": "#akcia"
            }
        ],
        "img": "DSC04934.jpg"
    }
]
```

And here is a code snippet from my AsyncTask:

```
 @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
        jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                .getJSONfromURL("http://guri.sk/mapped/mapped.json");

        try {
            // Locate the array name in JSON
            event = jsonobject.getJSONArray("events");

            for (int i = 0; i < event.length(); i++) {
                jsonobject = event.getJSONObject(i);
                lat2[i] = jsonobject.getDouble("lat");
                lon2[i] = jsonobject.getDouble("lon");
                text1[i] = jsonobject.getString("text");
                number = i;
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat2[i], lon2[i])).title(text1[i]));
        }
    }
```

How I initialize:

```
 double[] lat2 = new double[10];
 double[] lon2 = new double[10];
 String[] text1 = new String[10];
```

Comment: `lat2` or `jsonobject` are `null`. Have you debugged this yourself yet?

Comment: yes. And what I got is null pointer exception. But when I use normal double variables everything works fine. But then I got only one value and not both

Comment: Well, yes. That means that you're trying to access methods or properties of an object that is `null`. When you hit the breakpoint, is it `lat2` or `jsonobject` that is `null`. Then, how could that happen?

Comment: Oh, I initialized it like double[] lat2;

Comment: Which line throws null pointer exception?

Comment: now there is no null pointer exception but I am getting just the first object, please reload the question to see edits

Comment: I see no edits. You could have shown now how you initialised your arrays. What do you mean with `i am getting just the first object`?

Comment: When you look into my JSON posted above you see two objects in my "events" array with the same variables. e.g. "lat", "lon" etc. And I am only getting the information in first parenthesis not hte second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer to your problem after edit:**

If your JSON has two elements then after for loop value of number will be 1, and then in onPostExecute for loop will execute only for first element in array. So I think you should set value of number before for loop:

```
number = event.length();
for (int i = 0; i < event.length(); i++) {
    jsonobject = event.getJSONObject(i);
    lat2[i] = jsonobject.getDouble("lat");
    lon2[i] = jsonobject.getDouble("lon");
    text1[i] = jsonobject.getString("text");
}
```

Comment: Hi, i tried your answer, and now I get null pointer exception at line `mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat2[i], lon2[i])).title(text1[i]));` Can you tell me why ? It works when single item is in there

Comment: The problem must be that the JSON is improperly configured.

Comment: The problem was that it's not possible to use for loop in the onPostExecute. So I dded a method for it and it works now. Thanks for helping with solution

Comment: it's quite weird that you cannot use loop in onPostExecute (and I didn't know about that). Where you find information about that?

Comment: I just tried to find the solution by my own. So I tried to wrap it in a method because when I executed the code to place a marker once it worked but more than once not. So I experimented a bit

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't directly use for whatever reason for loop in onPostExecute of AsyncTask. You have to wrap it in a method. Here is the code snippet that works:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
        jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                .getJSONfromURL("http://guri.sk/mapped/mapped.json");

        try {
            // Locate the array name in JSON
            event = jsonobject.getJSONArray("events");
            number = event.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < event.length(); i++) {
                jsonobject = event.getJSONObject(i);
                lat2[i] = jsonobject.getDouble("lat");
                lon2[i] = jsonobject.getDouble("lon");
                text1[i] = jsonobject.getString("text");
                //Log.e("TAG","lat2:"+lat2[i]+"lon2:"+lon2[i]);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        placeMarkers();
    }
}
public void placeMarkers(){
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        Log.e("TAG","lat2:"+lat2[i]+"lon2:"+lon2[i]);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat2[i], lon2[i])).title(text1[i]));
    }
}
```